# How to save values from a spinner in sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite, spinner

I implemented a spinner in my `Unterkunft Activity` which is populated by data from sqlite database.
In this activity I have a few `edit texts` and this `spinner`. I want the inserted values and the chosen value from the spinner to be saved in a database. There is no problem with the edit texts values. But how can I save the spinner value in the database?

I added the `Unterkunft acitvity`

```
public class activity_unterkunft extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseHelper myDb;
    Button btn_save;
    Spinner ChooseProject;
    EditText Entfernung,Price,MWST;


    private BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_unterkunft);
        myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        ChooseProject = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.ChooseProject);
        Entfernung = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Entfernung);
        Price = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Preis);
        MWST = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.MwSt);
        btn_save=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_save);
        loadSpinnerData();
        SaveData();


        //++++++++++++BOTTOM NAVIGATION BAR++++++++++++//
        bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView);

        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item){
                if (item.getItemId()==R.id.menu_start){
                    startActivity(new Intent(activity_unterkunft.this, MainActivity.class));
                } else if(item.getItemId()==R.id.menu_allgemein){
                    startActivity(new Intent(activity_unterkunft.this, activity_allgemein.class));
                } else if(item.getItemId()==R.id.menu_transport){
                    startActivity(new Intent(activity_unterkunft.this, activity_transport.class));
                } else if(item.getItemId()==R.id.menu_rechnung){
                    startActivity(new Intent(activity_unterkunft.this, activity_rechnung.class));
                } else if(item.getItemId()==R.id.menu_unterkunft){
                    startActivity(new Intent(activity_unterkunft.this, activity_unterkunft.class));
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.menu_unterkunft);
    }

    /**
     * Function to load the spinner data from SQLite database
     * */
    private void loadSpinnerData() {
        // database handler
        DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper (getApplicationContext());

        // Spinner Drop down elements
        List<String> projects = db.getAllProjects();

        // Creating adapter for spinner
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, projects);

        // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
        dataAdapter
                .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        ChooseProject.setPrompt("Projekt auswählen");


        // attaching data adapter to spinner
        ChooseProject.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    }


    //++++++++++++Save Data++++++//
    public void SaveData(){
        btn_save.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        boolean isInserted = myDb.createUnterkunft(
                                Integer.valueOf(Price.getText().toString()),
                                Integer.valueOf(MWST.getText().toString()),
                                Integer.valueOf(Entfernung.getText().toString())
                        );
                        if(isInserted=true)
                            Toast.makeText(activity_unterkunft.this, "Daten gespeichert", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        else
                            Toast.makeText(activity_unterkunft.this, "Daten nicht gespeichert", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Please see: [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  `setOnItemSelectedListener` to get the spinner value

```
   String item; 

    ChooseProject.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
                   item =String.ValueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(pos));
                }
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                }
            });
```

Then you can save the `item` to databases.

Comment: I implemented your idea and changed it a little bit.
Instead of
`item =String.ValueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(pos));`
I use
`selectedspinner =parent.getSelectedItem().toString();`
But I have still the problem that always the first value is saved in the DB. Although I select the second for example. Do you know how I can solve this?

Comment: I solved it! I use now `selectedspinner = (String) ChooseProject.getSelectedItem();` 
Thank you anyway!!